# Laravel polymorphic relationship with pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Assume I have posts and videos that can be seen by multiple users.

```
- users
  - id

- posts
  - id

- videos
  - id

- user_accessables (pivot)
  - id
  - user_id
  - accessable_id
  - accessable_type
```

In an example like that, I have set my User relationship like so but something feels wrong

```
class User extends Model {
    public function posts() {
         return $this->morphedByMany(
                       Post::class,
                       'accessable',
                       'user_accessables'
         );
    }

    public function videos() {
         return $this->morphedByMany(
                       Video::class,
                       'accessable',
                       'user_accessables'
         );
    }


   public function allowedEntities() {
       return ($this->posts)->merge($this->videos);
   }
}
```

With the `allowedEntities()` I can get a collection of both models joined together.

However, I think the use of polymorphic relationship is returning a collection of entities through relationship rather than needing a combiner relationship, right?

I am having problems with understanding polymorphic with pivot table (the tag example in documentation doesn't seem like same scenario).

Because now I can't do:

```
$collection = collect(); // multiple models of Video & Post
$user->allowedEntities()->sync($collection);
```

Comment: Your relationships are correct. It's not possible to define a relationship that returns all related models combined.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonas Staudenmeir said is not possible to have a relationship that returns all related model, BUT you can define a method on the model that returns a query builder object with all entities you need (search with on the docs).